# How to make my MacBook into a Wifi hotspot without the actual internet connection

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I need to show some demonstrations at an upcoming conference where I run a node.js server on my machine,  and let the audience connect to it (I'll give the IP address).

The "Internet Sharing" capability of OSX works great if my MacBook have the Internet connection (via Ethernet), but that option is not available if it doesn't have the Internet connection.

All I need is a local (isolated from the Internet) WiFi connection between my MacBook and audiences devices. I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This type of question would be better over on SuperUser.com.  You will likely get better answers there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a local(non-internet)hotspot in your MacBook.Just follow the instructions below:

1.Open the network menu item in the menu bar of the Finder and select       `"Create Network"`

[image]

2.In the dialog that appears set the `Network name` and `Channel`

[image]

3.Depending on the "Security" selection you may have to enter a passphrase(Not on all Devices).

Comment: This menu is gone on macOS 11.4

Answer (score 1):

Take a small switch with you so you get a connection to a Network. Then configure that network manually and everything should be up and running.

Comment: While this is a the practical, always working answer, it it not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of MacOS you need to first enable "show legacy networks and options" from within the "Advanced..." preferences menu within "Network Preferences".

Comment: I did this, but in macOS Sonoma (14.0 Beta (23A5286i)), I can't find the option to create a network.